# Idiomatic way to declare 2D, 3D vector types in Rust?

Tags: types, rust, linear-algebra

I'm looking to write some small library that use 2D and 3D points or directions in space 
(vector in vector/matrix sense, not Rust's `Vec`).

Rust doesn't impose rules here, so you can make a tuple of floats, or a new `struct` with `x, y, z` members. or a single `data: [f64; 3]` member.

The reason I'd like to define a type here instead of using `[f64; 3]`, is so I can declare methods such as `length`, `normalized`, also `Add`, `Sub` operators.

Whats a good basis to declare small 2D - 3D fixed sized data types on?

---

Note, while there are good existing libraries, I'd like to write my own since it only needs some basic operations, and I like to understand whats going on internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should most certainly use a library for that! There are many good ones (see below) and they mostly don't occur any overhead, even if you don't use all the features. It will save you a lot of time, trust me.

---

But for educational purposes, here are some thought on how I would approach designing such a library. What I would consider "idiomatic" in Rust.

- Use a `struct` with `x`, `y` and `z` fields instead of an array or tuple. That makes it very natural to access these individual scalars, e.g. `pos.x`.
- Implement all relevant operator overloads (e.g. `std::ops`), so that you can simply add and subtract vectors.
- Provide useful and commonly used methods, like `length` and `normalize`.
- Unless its for a very specific/narrow use case, you likely want to make the scalar type generic. You then likely want to use something like `num_traits` to add trait bounds.
- You can also try to abstract over different dimensions via const generics, but that makes your job even harder.
- Use strong typing! Rust is all about strong typing, so make use of that. For example, [distinguish between point (location) and vector (displacement)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/645827/340615). And maybe also directions (normalized vectors). And while we're at it, also have separate types for points represented in homogeneous coordinates.

But again, doing all that properly takes time and care. I did that once and ended up with [`lina`](https://github.com/LukasKalbertodt/lina/), which I am very happy with. Though it's not very widely used yet and maybe uses too much strong typing for some people. But as I said there are many other good libraries: [`cgmath`](https://crates.io/crates/cgmath),
[`nalgebra`](https://nalgebra.org/),
[`glam`](https://crates.io/crates/glam/),
[`ultraviolet`](https://crates.io/crates/ultraviolet)
[`vek`](https://crates.io/crates/vek), and more!

Comment: Updated question to reference points *or* directions in space. Mainly because for the purpose of this question is not an important difference (even if they end up being two different types).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend defining a *newtype*, i.e. a tuple struct with a single member.

```
struct Vector3D([f64; 3]); // wraps an array
struct Vector3D((f64, f64, f64)); // wraps a 3-tuple
```

The fields of a tuple struct can be accessed by using their position (starting from zero) as the name of the field. For example, if you have a variable `v` of type `Vector3D`, `v.0` would evaluate to the inner field. You can choose to make this field public or not; to make it public, add the keyword `pub` just before the name of the field's type.

```
struct Vector3D(pub [f64; 3]);
```

Note that this new `Vector3D` doesn't inherit any methods or traits from the wrapped type; it's up to you to provide whatever API you like on this type.

Comment: `struct Vector3D(pub [f64; 3]);`, this seems to be a good start, however getting even basic traits like `Index` back isn't really obvious since it can't be derived.

Answer (score 1):

Like Francis said, you can use a wrapper type, but if you don't need it to be truly distinct from the other types and to be able take advantage of an existing type's methods, you can use a type alias:

```
type Vector3D = (f64, f64, f64);
```

or

```
type Vector3D = [f64; 3];
```

Comment: Can you define operators such as `Add`, `Sub` on these types?, was part of the question, and attempting to do so gives errors.

Comment: Simple impls work for me; can you show me the code that fails?

Comment: Maybe worth including simple example in answer? - this is an example that fails. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1cc78c4daff5e810e39beebc9bc20154&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: It's because the std::ops::Add trait is defined in a different crate; if you were to introduce your own trait in the same crate as Vector, it would work. This should not be a problem with a wrapper type, though.

Comment: In addition, your example has one other error; you can see the isolated E0117 issue here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f70f8b7fbeac99cc177ef918d53b07f&version=stable&backtrace=0.